# Lightning Component not rendering properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have inputCheckbox which is on the Lightning tab.

On click of button, I'm trying to set the value of checkbox to true. It seems inputCheckbox is not rendering properly. When I click on button first time I'm getting the value of **component.find("inputCheck")** undefined but when I click the second time I'm getting the value. Sometimes this number of click increases to 4 to 5 times.

**Component:**

```
 <lightning:tabset>
        <lightning:tab id="tab1">
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="inputCheck"/>
            <div>
                <button id="saveButton" onclick="{!c.ButtonClicked}">Save</button>
            </div>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
```

Controller:

```
 ButtonClicked : function(component,event,helper){

        component.find("inputCheck").set("v.value", true); 
    }
```

Comment: voting to close as the question has not been updated with a reproduceable code sample

Answer (score 3):

using the "lightning:input" component, You can set the value by using `("v.checked", true)` instead of `"v.value"`

as for the ui:inputCheckbox, "v.value" should work. I tested in my community with your exact same code, and the checkbox is set to true when clicking the button.

if you have other functions or code interacting with your component, you might want to share it.